l3keys : how to generate several keys (lines= programmatically
I am repeating keys following the same pattern for different modules. I would like to generate the code to avoid typo and ability to quickly adjust the pattern.
Bonus question : how to have \mykey{module / submodule} {A} {ValueA}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    
    % Function to generate key definitions as text
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \generate_keys:n #1
    {
        {
            key1_#1 .tl_set:c = {l_tmp_A_#1_tl},
            key2_#1 .tl_set:c = {l_tmp_B_#1_tl},
        }
    }
    
    % Inject the generated key definitions into the key module
    % Should be like having the pattern written with #1 applied
    \keys_define:nn { mymodule }
    {
        \generate_keys:n { a }
        \generate_keys:n { b }
    }
     
    % Set values using the keys
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key1_a = value1A, key2_b = value2B }
    
    % Print the values to verify
    \l_tmp_A_a_tl \par  % Should print "value1A"
    \l_tmp_B_b_tl      % Should print "value2B"
    
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


@Skillmon's  answer solved the problem, just a suggestion the key side should not be underscored, maybe "-"  or nothing, the tl side should. You wouldn't expect users to use keys, in an expl3 catcode regime, by the way also now you do not need to include expl3 as it is incorporated into the kernel.

You just need to expand your \generate_keys:n calls. For this you can use \keys_define:ne which will fully expand its second argument, and since the contents of your \generate_keys:n don't need protection from further expanding you should be done with that:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    
    % Function to generate key definitions as text
    \cs_new:Npn \generate_keys:n #1
    {
      key1_#1 .tl_set:c = {l_tmp_A_#1_tl},
      key2_#1 .tl_set:c = {l_tmp_B_#1_tl},
    }
    
    % Inject the generated key definitions into the key module
    % Should be like having the pattern written with #1 applied
    \keys_define:ne { mymodule }
    {
        \generate_keys:n { a }
        \generate_keys:n { b }
    }
     
    % Set values using the keys
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { key1_a = value1A, key2_b = value2B }
    
    % Print the values to verify
    \l_tmp_A_a_tl \par  % Should print "value1A"
    \l_tmp_B_b_tl      % Should print "value2B"
    
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


It does not compile for me.
a1.tex: error: 22: No property given in definition of key '\generate_keys:n(LaTeX) {a}\generate_keys:n {b}'. }
The generate_keys is not expanded properly.

@user27933604 yes, I overlooked that you defined \generate_keys:n as protected in your question, I'll update the code.
